# Creating ASP.NET Core 3.0 Angular Wep Application Image From Linux

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core

I have built an ASP.NET Core application that uses Angular on the front-end. It runs fine on my Windows machine as well as in a macOS environment. Now I would like to create a Docker image of that application based on a Linux image. It seems that this should be common enough but I have failed to come up with anything with a Google search and my current attempts fail. This is what I have so far:

```
FROM ubuntu AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install curl libunwind-dev libc6 libgcc1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libicu60 liblttng-ust0 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 zlib1g -y

COPY ./dotnet-install.sh .
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c Current
RUN ls -l 

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN ./dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./dotnet-install.sh .
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c Release

COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The shell script dotnet-install.sh comes from Microsoft web site. The problem that I am dealing with right now is that the CLI 'dotnet' is not found so the build errors out when it is invoked. Any pointers on what needs to be done to successfully build the application and what needs to be installed to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to build the image from scratch? There's no need for that. Microsoft provides both .NET Core SDK and runtime images. Your Dockerfile should just look like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk as build

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet as final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

As an additional perk, the Microsoft images are multi-arch, so you can then deploy that Dockerfile to either a Windows or Linux container.

Comment: OK. I will try it. I thought that was for just a Microsoft container.  I noticed on the Dockerfile that you referenced, during the build there is not any creation of /app. Is that the default? Once I have the image. Can I start a container like 'docker run -d -p 5001:5001 <image>'? How do I tell which port to map?

Comment: I tried this build. I ran into two problems. First, since this is an Angular ASP.NET Web app the package manager 'npm' could not be found. The build failed. This image doesn't seem to include npm. I downloaded the latest version of node (12.11.1) and extracted it in the image. This gave me the second error when I tried to run the image:<br/> docker logs bsoftapp <br/>
> It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs 
>
> Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? 
> Install a .NET Core SDK from: aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: No, the build image doesn't have npm, but  you can install it as a build step. You can also choose to introduce another stage with an image that does contain npm, and do the work in that stage and copy it out later. The final stage only contains the runtime, so at that point all you can do is copy from previous stages and run the app. Any work needs to happen in previous stages.

Comment: This really boils down to how to build a Dockerfile, and is not ASP.NET Core specific. You should do some more learning in that area. Pluralsight has some good courses, and there's plenty of guides online.

Comment: I just need to know what image to start with. The image you suggested doesn't have npm. When I overcame  the npm issue it seemed like I needed to use the SDK image rather than the one suggested. Should I use the SDK for both the build and the runtime? But then I will need the ASP.NET runtime?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the concept of stages in a Dockerfile. You use whatever image you need in each stage. The only thing that's retained is the final stage, which would be your runtime. In other words, you'd have a .NET Core SDK stage to build and publish your app, a Node stage to run any of your npm scripts/build tasks, etc. Then you just copy from those stages into your final stage.

Comment: I think I understand the stages. It is when I run that final stage image that I get a message that indicates I need the .NET SDK in that image also which would seem to indicate that I need the .NET SDK in both the build stage and the final stage which kind of defeats the purpose of stages at all.

Comment: Have you actually tried using the official runtime image?

Comment: Yes. As I indicated earlier the container immediately terminates. Looking at the logs it appears that the reason it terminated was because it couldn’t find a .NET SDK.

Comment: I have added docker support to this web project and it seems that npm is missing from the build and runtime image. It doesn't appear that the same trick of copying the compressed file and 'tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v12.11.1-linux-x64.tar.gz' to install npm works with the Dockerfile that is installed as part of Docker support.

Comment: That was happening because you weren't using the official runtime image, but rather one you're creating yourself based on the Ubuntu image, and again, npm is not part of these images. You should have a separate stage based on an npm image, that does your npm build. Then you copy out of that.

Comment: I just added Docker support to the web project the Dockerfile that was produced from that action I am assuming is the 'official runtime image' (it uses mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim for the runtime and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster for the build) . If I set the docker-compose project that again comes as a result of adding Docker support as my startup project I get an error during build that npm could not be found.

Comment: Yes. Npm is not part of the image. You just need to add another stage, with an image that does have npm, and do the npm build in that stage.

Comment: The problem is probably that you have npm as a build task in your project. Don't do it that way. Build your project in one stage, npm build in another, then copy into runtime stage.

Comment: That would be the question then what image to use that has npm and ASP.NET Core 3.0 SDK? The images that Microsoft is using when adding Docker support don't have npm and the project that Microsoft supplies as part of the template does a build with npm.

Comment: That's what you're not getting. You don't need both in the same image. Use another stage for the npm build, with an image with just npm.

Comment: The project template is setup for a standard deployment to like IIS or something. Remove the build task for npm from the project and do it as part of the Dockerfile instead. That is how you'd deploy with Docker.